# NativeBase Tabs function onChangeTab causing app to freeze

Tags: react-native

my versions from package.json
"expo": "^30.0.1"
"native-base": "^2.8.1"
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz"

the app freezes when i try the below code

```
<Tabs tabBarPosition="bottom" initialPage={1} locked onChangeTab={({ i }) => this.setState({ currentTab: i })}>
    <Tab heading={<TabHeading>
                <Icon name="bell" type='SimpleLineIcons' style={{fontSize:22}} />
                <Text style={{color:(this.state.header == 'Snapshot'?Colors.themeBlue:'black')}}>Snapshot</Text>
        </TabHeading>} 
    >
        <Text> tab 1</Text>
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading={<TabHeading>
                <Icon name="compass" type="SimpleLineIcons" style={{fontSize:22}} />
                <Text style={{color:(this.state.header == 'Discover'?Colors.themeBlue:'black')}}>Discover</Text>
            </TabHeading>} style={{backgroundColor:'#e8e8e8'}}
    >
        <Text> tab 2</Text>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
this.setState({ currentTab: i })}
```

To

```
this.setState.bind({ currentTab: i })}
```